# Asynchronous JavaScript: Proper way to make loops?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Last few days I'm thinking about JavaScript. Lot of frameworks offer functions only in asynchronous/promises way. But as I'm used to program in synchronous languages (PHP, Python, ...), I struggle with some basic ideas.

For example:

## How to make loops with asynchronous function properly?

Let's say we have function `nextValue()` which returns string from some list of words. Our task is find word "Foo" in this list and print the index where the "Foo" word is located.

If the `nextValue()` function was synchronous, we could do it very easy:

```js
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; !found; i++) {
    if (nextValue() == 'Foo') {
        console.log("'Foo' found at index " + i);
        found = true;
    }
}
```

But if the function was asynchronous, the only idea I've got is to make function and call it recursively until we find the "Foo" word:

```js
var i = 0;
(function checkNextValue(){
    nextValue(function(value){
        if (value == 'Foo') {
            console.log("'Foo' found at index " + i);
        } else {
            i++;
            checkNextValue();
        }
    });
})();
```

But I see few problems here:

1. The asynchronous example is much harder to read. Imagine if we needed two nested loops or even more.
2. **RAM usage. What if the "Foo" value will be at index 1000? There will be 1000 running functions in the memory "thanks" to the recursion.**
3. And it's complicated in general and much harder to write the code, or even re-use the code in another place (we can't simply `return` value, we are forced to use callback or promise again).

What am I missing here? Thanks for you ideas :-)

Comment: you using promises?

Comment: Yes, asynchronous code is slightly more complex than synchronous code. `async/await` syntax is attempting to simplify that. No, since the callbacks are asynchronous you won't have 1000 functions "running in RAM".

Comment: Seems it should never happen in real world. Please, provide an example where you need to iterate something asynchronously.
In your case, yes, chaining seems the only one correct solution with all of disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

> How to make loops with asynchronous function properly?

Javascript adopts the concept of iteration, more likely others languages do, so, iteration doesn't really take care about sync/async code execution. There are many ways to achieve async iteration:

1. [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
2. [Observables](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable)
3. [Async Iteration](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration)

are the more clean and eloquent ways.

> The asynchronous example is much harder to read. Imagine if we needed two nested loops or even more.

`Async` code execution is often harder to read than the sync one, by the way, you can write a clean way. Let's do it implementing something like [`Array#extras`](https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-array-extras/)

```js
Array.prototype.asyncForEach = function asyncForEach(callback, context = null) {
  const self = this;
  let index = 0;
  
  function iterate() { setTimeout(iteration, 1500); }  
  function iteration() {
  
    callback.call(context, self[index], index, self);
    
    index += 1;
    if(self.length > index) {
      iterate();
    }
  }
  
  return iterate();
};

['hello dear', 'how are you?', 'I am fine, thanks']
  .asyncForEach((item, index, list) => {
  
    console.log(Date.now(), `Iteration at {i: ${index}}`, item);
  })
;
```

> RAM usage. What if the "Foo" value will be at index 1000? There will be 1000 running functions in the memory "thanks" to the recursion.

Of course RAM usage is a big concern, but, you have to mind that Javascript is based on [non blocking I/O](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/), so, your async iteration will take less than a normal sync code takes.

> And it's complicated in general and much harder to write the code, or even re-use the code in another place (we can't simply return value, we are forced to use callback or promise again).

This regards all the languages, you're quite new here, you will find it comfortable as long as you keep going working with Javascript!